# « Dont » ou « que » dans un contexte spécifique

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

On se méfie **de** quelque chose, donc on peut parler de quelque chose **dont** on se méfie. Cependant, je lisais ce matin et je suis tombé sur la phrase suivante :

> Pour nous autres humains, c’est des pattes **qu**’il faut se méfier [...]

*L'énigme de l'anguille et autres bizarreries animales*, P. 307

Je l'ai relue deux ou trois fois mais je n'arrive pas à me convaincre qu'il faut bien un « que » ici et pas un « dont », vu que l'objet est « des pattes » et la construction est « se méfier de quelque chose ». Le livre me paraît super bien écrit (et super intéressant d'ailleurs), et donc je pense qu'il est plus probable que je rate quelque chose plutôt que la traductrice a fait une erreur.

Concrètement, est-ce que quelqu'un peut m'expliquer l'emploi de « que » ici et non « dont » ?

Comment: Moi je pense plutôt que dans l'usage courant, on va trouver les deux, _dont_ étant peut-être le mot "correct", mais _que_ étant utilisé sans trop de difficulté. Quand je lis cette phrase, je peux mettre _dont_ ou _que_ indifféremment sans sentir de vraie différence. Comme le dit Luke, cela est peut-être possible ici en raison de la tournure _c'est ... que_.

Comment: @Frank Utiliser *dont* est une hypercorrection qui sonne mal à mes oreilles. *Que* était quasiment le seul utilisé jusqu'au milieu des années 1970 et reste encore majoritaire au moins à l'écrit d'après les [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+cela+que+je+parle+%2B+de+%C3%A7a+que+je+parle%2Cde+cela+dont+je+parle+%2B+de+%C3%A7a+dont+je+parle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @jlliagre Bon. Pour moi, ça sonne à peu près pareil. Je dois être trop correct ;-)

Comment: @None Oh, wait. I misread the sentence. You're right, it's not the same at all. The *de* is perfectly present already in the *des*, not simplified / swapped out as in my other link!

Comment: @Frank Pour moi, c'est du même ordre que dire *c'est celui que je t'ai parlé* au lieu de *c'est celui dont je t'ai parlé* sauf que cette derniere évolution va dans l'autre sens. Hyper-incorrection ? ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Intéressant. Je n'arrive pas à voir une aussi grande différence pour ma part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La phrase citée dans la question est tout à fait correcte. Personnellement c'est ce que je dirais, sans être cependant surprise par l'emploi de *dont*.

Dans la phrase en question le gallicisme *c'est...que* est employé pour mettre en relief une proposition dont le verbe (*se méfier*) introduit un complément avec la préposition *de*.

Par ailleurs il faut se pencher sur le sens de [*dont*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dont) qui vient du latin *de unde* qui signifie *d'où*, la préposition *de* est déjà contenu dans *dont*.  C'est pour cela qu'un grand nombre de grammairiens considèrent que les tournures du type « c'est des pattes dont il faut se méfier » comme pléonastiques, parce que si on enlève l'emphase exprimée par *c'est... dont* ça donne :  <strike>*Il faut se méfier de des pattes.*</strike>, ce que personne ne dit, bien sûr.

La phrase « c’est **les** pattes dont il faut se méfier »  ne soulèvera jamais d'objections de la part des grammairiens.

*Parler de* a une construction parallèle à *se méfier de* et on pourra lire l'article « C'est DE CELA DONT je te parle » dans [Les chroniques Grevisse](https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/norme-et-usage/c-est-de-cela-dont-je-te-parle) pour une explication plus technique que la mienne.

Voici le [point du vue](http://jeanjosephjulaud.fr/2013/04/cest-de-cela-que-je-parle/) d'un « puriste » qui considère comme fautive l'utilisation de *dont* dans le cas présent : « C’est de cela que je parle… C’est de cela dont je parle…On entend les deux, mais l’un des deux est fautif. »

---

*[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/pronoms-relatifs)* rejette aussi l'utilisation de *dont* quand on introduit l'antécédent par *de* :

> *Dont* reprend *un groupe nominal* précédé de la préposition *de* ; c'est l'équivalent de *de qui, de quoi, duquel ou d'où* :
>
> > *l'homme **dont** je suis amoureuse = l'homme **de qui** je suis amoureuse ou l'homme **duquel** je suis amoureuse*
>
> [...]
>
> Du fait de ce *de* sous-entendu dans *dont*, on ne peut pas employer *dont* lorsque l'antécédent est lui-même déjà introduit par la préposition *de*, sous peine de redondance. On ne dira donc pas :
>
> > **C'est **de** ce modèle **dont** on m'a parlé.*
>
> Mais :
>
> > *C'est ce modèle **dont** on m'a parlé.*
>
> ou :
>
> > *C'est **de** ce modèle **qu**'on m'a parlé.*

Comment: Merci pour la réponse détaillée - c'est exactement ce que je cherchais!

Comment: Dans "si on enlève _c'est ... que_", je ne vois pas trop comment "c'est des pattes dont il faut se méfier" contient "c'est ... que". _Dont_ est un pronom relatif ici au même titre que _que_ dans _c'est ... que_, si bien que l'expression serait plutôt _ce sont ... dont_, équivalente à _c'est ... que_, mais si on l'enlève, on se retrouve avec _il faut se méfier des pattes_, sans redondance: le premier _de_ part avec le _dont_ de l'expression. En tout cas, j'interpréterais plutôt dans ce sens.

Comment: @Frank Typo, corrigée, merci.

Comment: OK, mais je ne vois toujours pas pourquoi il reste un _de des_ après avoir enlevé _c'est ... dont_. Le _dont_ n'emporte pas avec lui le _de_? Tu dis bien que _de_ est contenu dans _dont_. Si tu enlèves _dont_, tu enlèves donc aussi _de_, et il n'y pas de redondance _de des_?

Comment: @Frank Si j'enlève un des 2 de je change  le sens de départ et je ne fais pas que supprimer l'emphase. Ce qu'il faut comprendre c'est que la préposition est présente 2 fois si on emploie dont.  J'avais trouvé après coup  une explication peut-être plus claire que la mienne sur le blog de Jean-Joseph Julaud et rajouté en edit, ce sera peut-être mieux expliqué que je ne l'ai fait !

Comment: Ou alors, pour essayer de partir de ce que je comprends de ce que tu comprends (pas toujours facile de se mettre dans la tête d'autrui...), quand tu transformes la phrase tu éprouves visiblement le besoin d'enlever "de" (c'est le de de "dont" puisque "des" reste "des"), alors pourquoi le mettre ce "de" quand tu mets "c'est " ? Le mettre t'obligeant à utiliser "dont"...

Comment: @None Je crois que je comprends mieux maintenant avec l'explication du Robert :-) Merci!